# Craft CMS shows disabled entry page

Tags: entries, 404-page

Entry is disabled
https://monosnap.com/file/l8tgvr5Fxpw0OXPbpcwiI57JmZjL51

But despite that on its address I see its template loaded only without entry data.

I expected to see 'Page Not Found'.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the beginning of your case study entry template:

```
{% if entry is not defined %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

Do you have a route set up for your case studies?

I've got routing set up on a client site that has the route `/case-studies/*` pointing to template `/_cs/entry.twig`

That makes it try to the load the template, whether or not there's an entry at all. So it needs the extra bit to check if the entry is real/published.